# I need to search multiple keywords

Tags: java

I need to scan a log for multiple keywords ERROR,OS,ARCH.Below code works with a single keyword search

```
import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class ErrorScanner
  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("Users/home/test.txt"));
        boolean ifError = false;
        while(s.hasNextLine())
         {  
         String nextLine = s.nextLine();       
             if(nextLine.contains("ERROR"))
             {
                 System.out.println("Failed" + " " + nextLine);
                 ifError = true;
             }
         }     
         if(! ifError)
         {
             System.out.println("Nothing found");
         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use use `.contains()` three times, once for each keyword?

Comment: `} else if (nextLine.contains("OS")) {...} else if ...` ??

Comment: Or ... `if(nextLine.contains("ERROR") || nextLine.contains("OS") || ...) {...}` if you don't care about the differences...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can express it more elegantly using a regex:

```
if (nextLine.matches(".*(ERROR|OS|ARCH).*")) {
    System.out.println("Failed" + " " + nextLine);
    ifError = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if (nextLine.contains("ERROR")
    || nextLine.contains("OS")
    || nextLine.contains("ARCH")) {
    // ...    
}
```

Or a more sophisticated solution, useful if there are many keywords and the line is long:

```
// declared before the while loop
Set<String> keywords = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("ERROR", "OS", "ARCH"));

// inside the while loop
for (String word : nextLine.split("\\s+")) {
    if (keywords.contains(word)) {
        System.out.println("Failed" + " " + nextLine);
        ifError = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've used a variation of your second approach to good effect.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add multiple string contains check in your code using OR. Here you go:

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class ErrorScanner
  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("Users/home/test.txt"));
        boolean ifError = false;
        while(s.hasNextLine())
         {  
         String nextLine = s.nextLine();       
             if(nextLine.contains("ERROR") || nextLine.contains("OS") || nextLine.contains("ARCH"))
             {
                 System.out.println("Failed" + " " + nextLine);
                 ifError = true;
             }
         }     
         if(! ifError)
         {
             System.out.println("Nothing found");
         }
     }
  }
```